# When I create a project, I did " git push -u origin master" push fail

Tags: gitlab, git-push

To https://git.misynergy.com/imal/eureka-registry.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.misynergy.com/imal/eureka-registry.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

When I execute the command `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Did you try what it recommends to do to fix the issue? (`Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`)

Comment: While you worked on your changes, somebody else pushed to the remote repository. You have to merge these changes into your local working copy before you can push your changes. In the simplest case a `git pull` will suffice (if the other commit didn't change the same files as you did). But maybe you may need to do a merge.

Comment: Yes i tried "git pull" but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

it seems your remote version of current branch was modified. You can try to integrate remote changes into your local brunch by

1. Checkout to branch you want to push
2. Run `git pull origin <branch>`. Here, you may get some conflicts or divered branches, but that's another topic and problem. If you get smth like that you can just try to rebase your local `<branch>` on `origin/<branch>` and solve conflicts manually
3. Once rebased or successfully pulled, you can push your local `<branch>` to remote.

Answer (score 0):

run `git diff` and see what the changes are between the two branches.

if you are comfortable with the changes, run `git pull --rebase`